# InfluxDB + Flux: Get most recent timestamp for a measurement via Python API

Tags: python, influxdb, flux-influxdb

I need to get the highest (aka most recent) timestamp for a specific Measurement in InfluxDB 2.0 via the Flux query language using the Python API.

I have used the below query to get a timestamp out, but I'm unsure how to ensure that the timestamp I extract via this method is indeed the most recent one.

In particular, the indexing I use, `last_data[0]`, is arbitrary as `last_data` is a list of objects like `<influxdb_client.client.flux_table.FluxTable object at 0x00000193FA906AC8>`, which I am unsure how to interpret. The timestamps do not seem to be sorted.

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, WriteOptions

client = InfluxDBClient(url=self.influx_url, token=self.token, org=self.org_id, debug=False)

last_data = client.query_api().query(
    f'from(bucket:"{self.influx_bucket}") |> range(start: -100d) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "{devices[0]}") |> last()'
)
timestamp = last_data[0].records[0]["_stop"]
print(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `_stop` is used to tell you the end of your time range. In your case, it would be just a timestamp of the query execution time as you don't enter the end date for the range. To get the timestamp for measurement you need to use `_time`.
To get the result you want you would probably need to add `|> group()` before calling the `last` function. So it would be

```
last_data = client.query_api().query(
    f'from(bucket:"{self.influx_bucket}") |> range(start: -100d) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "{devices[0]}") |> group() |> last()'
```